# Facebook applications activation on a fan page

Tags: facebook

How do I activate an application I just created?

It just appears in the application section of the Developerspage and I'm confused about how to make it appear in my Facebook page.

Answer (score 1):

Edit settings of your application in the developers section. On the left side, choose View App Profile Page from Related links. 
When you visit your application profile page, choose Add to My Page on the left side and then choose the Page of yours.